# CefSharp and AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

since I am rather new to programming in C# (and creating applications in WPF), I would like to ask for your help on a certain task I received in the company I work.

We have implemented something we refer to as "JobCacheUpdater". Without delving into too much detail, our basic idea is as follows:

- our database contains several thousand projects with different bits of information
- we then want to load that information on our website asynchronously (AJAX)
- but instead of piecing together that information separately and every single time, we want to store and (pre-)render an HTML-string to a separate table on our database
- we then select a row from that table based on a ProjectID and that HTML-string basically shows the table with the needed information about the project

This "JobCacheUpdater" runs on a regular basis so that we can keep our table with the HTML-strings synchonized with our main table for all the projects.

Up until now we have used WatiN to have a browser run in the background which reads and renders the HTML-string, but my current task is to implement the Chromium Embedded Framework (Cef) instead to achieve the same thing.

Writing the basic code in a sample WPF project was easy enough but when I use some random URL of a project to read the source of that page and write it to a .txt file, I notice that only the "skeleton" of the website (if I may call it that) is loaded, but not the table containing the necessary information.

I wrote a class ChromeWrapper, which is as follows:

```
public class ChromeWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;
    private string _html = "";
    private bool _pageIsLoaded = false;

    public ChromeWrapper()
    {
        var settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");

        Cef.Initialize(settings, shutdownOnProcessExit: true, performDependencyCheck: true);

        _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty);
        _browser.BrowserSettings.ApplicationCache = CefState.Disabled;
    }

    public string GetHtml(string url)
    {
        _pageIsLoaded = false;

        while (!_browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        _browser.Load(url);
        _browser.LoadingStateChanged += BrowserLoadingStateChanged;

        while (!_pageIsLoaded)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        return _html;
    }

    private void BrowserLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if loading is complete - this event is called twice, one when loading starts
        // second time when it's finished
        // (rather than an iframe within the main frame).
        if (e.IsLoading) 
            return;

        _browser.LoadingStateChanged -= BrowserLoadingStateChanged;
        var htmlTask = e.Browser.MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
        htmlTask.ContinueWith(obj =>
                                  {
                                      _html = htmlTask.Result;
                                      _pageIsLoaded = true;
                                  });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_browser != null)
            _browser.Dispose();

        Cef.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

My MainWindows class instantiates ChromeWrapper as soon as Button1 is clicked and then saves the source to a .txt file on my desktop:

```
    private void Button1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var chrome = new ChromeWrapper())
        {
            var html = chrome.GetHtml(@"URL Test");
            var htmltPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "CefSharpTest2.html");

            File.WriteAllText(htmltPath, html);

            Process.Start(htmltPath);

            chrome.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Interestingly, if I initiate chrome.GetHtml *twice* in Button1Click, I do get the result I want, which leads me to the conclusion that there may be something wrong with the browser cache, but I'm not exactly sure.

Additional question: is there a way to programmatically clean the browser cache when starting the application?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Personally I'd ditch the nasty `While` loops, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/51/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example/Program.cs#L105 for an `async` version. Secondly if your `html` is being modified by an `ajax` call then you need to wait for the data to be rendered. There is no issue, your just not waiting long enough. `LoadingStateChanged` doesn't mean everything is finished, a web page could render infinitely.

Comment: Likely you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver and a bound object (see the `FAQ`) to be notified when your html has loaded.

Comment: Also, you didn't tag your question `cefsharp`.